# What's the difference between mlab/MongoDB atlas and self hosted mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vps, mlab, mongodb-atlas

Why people prefer using mlab over self hosted mongodb on their server (VPS). 
Mongodb hosted on VPS must be lot faster than mlab service . Still why do people use mongodb as a service from mlab or atlas ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same your question when I deployed my website to Heroku which used mlab.

Here is why I am using it:

1. mLab will take care of everything related to your database operation such as data backup, scaling, replication, maintaining clusters.
2. mlab guarantees high data and server availability.
3. mlab takes responsibility of disaster recovery.

This save a lot of time, resources, skill needed and technical consultant that I will face when I do all these stuff by myself.

Only one thing you should do: Pay them.